# SQL Server linked server for odbc...how does it work?

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I'm trying to connect a linked server in SQL Server 2012 Data Warehouse edition to an ODBC data source, and I have absolutely no idea what it wants.

The "Linked Server" box asks for (when I chose "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers") Product Name, Data Source, Provider String, Location, and Catalog, and I have no idea what to put into any of them.

My best guess is:

```
Provider Name:  I have absolutely no idea whatsoever,
Data Source:  The server name in the IBM Informix OCBS Driver Setup.
Provider String:  Also the server name?
Location:  The Host Name?
Catalog:  The Database Name?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, using Informix as a linked server on SQL Server is an aggravating task. Fortunately, people over on the DBA StackExchange site have it worked out. See [SQL Server --> Informix DB Linked Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171204/sql-server-informix-db-linked-server) over there for details... and lots of them.